# Suppress warnings in ms-access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

While developing forms in Access VBA I am trying to prevent access from adding a new record and then not giving any warning message. I can stop the record from being inserted but cannot supress the warning message. I have set warnings to false on the after update event (and set warnings to true on the close event ). Can anyone tell me which events I should code for this. The reason for doing this is only while I develop the forms

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. A first step could be adding the code you already wrote and explain his behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a click event for any buttons?  If so I would just suppress warnings in there.  This setting will remain this way until you close the database and open it again.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
```